# Flutter decrease blur of background of Dismissible widget the further it is dragged down

Tags: flutter

I display a Dismissible dialog in my screen. It makes the background blur when it is shown and the further it is dragged down it decreases it. This example works but my problem it that in `Listener` widget, its methods `onPointerMove, onPointerDown, onPointerSignal` react only to user inputs, and when I drag down a bit to dismiss it and I take my finger out of it, the transition of blurred background to no blur changes too suddenly. It works smooth only when I drag the modal all the way down, but when I take my finger off it, it just keeps track of the last position where I held my finger on screen and then removes blur of background when the dialog is completely dismissed.

I am doing this because I want keep track of how much the modal is drag down, so that I can take the percentage and adjust the value for `ImageFilter.blur`.

What I have been thinking as well to give `key` to some widget from `MyDialogModal` and get its position but the problem is that I can only get it if I keep my finger on the screen when `onPointerMove` is triggered, else it will not work.

Is there a way to add some listener that will always listen to my modal and always return its position so that blurred background to be adjusted accordingly? Or maybe could someone please suggest a better way on how to solve this problem?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned.fill(
          child: Container(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 15 * _percentageHeight, sigmaY: 15 * _percentageHeight),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Listener(
                  onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent event) {
                    double percentage = 1 - (_initialPosY! - event.position.dy).abs() / _keyMyDialog.currentContext!.size!.height;
                  setState(() => _percentageHeight = percentage);
                  },
                  onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) {
                    _initialPosY = event.position.dy;
                  },
                  onPointerSignal: (PointerSignalEvent event) {},
                  child: Dismissible(
                    key: const Key('my-dialog'),
                    direction: DismissDirection.down,
                    onDismissed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: MyDialogModal();
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
  }
```

Comment: can you please share the image of it so that i can understand it completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `onPointerUp` for when user stops dragging the `Dismissible` down and `_percentageHeight` is not at 0, meaning that the `Dismissible` is not fully down.

You could use a [Tween](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Tween-class.html) that goes from `_percentageHeight` to 1 to restore the blur at 100% with a custom `Duration`.

in `onPointerUp` you should call `_yourTween.animate(_animationController)` and then `listen` to its value changing, calling `setState` every time untill it stop at 1.